# How do I read individual records in a records-oriented json file?

Tags: python, json

I exported a .csv from pandas as [records-oriented JSON](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) for future use. However, I'm doing something wrong with reading it, not into pandas but as vanilla python.

How do I open the JSON file and read each record?

> [{"reference":"2019-73","Latitude":1.045,"Longitude":103.65,"date":"2019-09-30T00:00:00.000Z","year":2019,"description":",
>   SINGAPORE STRAITS.}, {...}, {...}, etc ]

My current approach just prints the entire (rather large) file.

```
review_json_filepath = os.path.join(data_directory)
with codecs.open(review_json_filepath, encoding='utf_8') as f:
    first_review_record = f.readline()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loads the json into a variable which you can then iterate through:

```
zzread=open('json.txt', 'r').read()      
data = json.loads(zzread) 

print(data)
[{"reference":"2019-73","Latitude":1.045,"Longitude":103.65,"date":"2019-09-30T00:00:00.000Z","year":2019,"description": "SINGAPORE STRAITS."},
{"reference":"2019-72","Latitude":1.045,"Longitude":103.65,"date":"2019-09-45T00:00:00.000Z","year":2019,"description": "SINGAPORE STRAITS."}] 


for item in jsondata: 
    print(item)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: `jsondata` is not defined, and it's probably better to use a context manager for the file. Also, I tested this on the JSON output of a simple DataFrame and it seems like it didn't work properly.

Comment: That’s strange, I’ll investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating the JSON using `pandas.to_json`, why not read it using [`pandas.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)?

Not to worry, it's also dead simple in pure Python:

```py
with open('../out/json_test.json', 'r') as file_1:
    json_res: dict = json.loads(file_1.read())
```

Comment: I'll need to do something with that later is pandas is mostly likely not going to be part of the solution. But, this does it so thanks very much.

Comment: @hrokr If it works and there are no better answers, please do accept it!